# Open doc file (97-2003 version) with python

Tags: python, cpu-word

I have 2 .doc files, one make on Word and other make in OpenOffice, the 2 doc files saved with Word 97-2003 version .
I try search a string inside the files using this function below

```
def procura_dentro_txt(file):       
for i, line in enumerate(open( funcoesDantas.short_name(file), errors="ignore")):
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
        mostraResultado(match.group(), file, pattern)
        #print("Encontrado1", match.group(), file)
```

But, in the file maked with Word, the program find the string correct.
in file maked at OpenOffice the python dont find the string.

Anyone may help me ?

Comment: You'll want to store and look at the result of `open(funcoesDantas.short_name(file))` to make sure that you got a valid file-handle, and you might want to drop`errors="ignore"`. If you didn't get a valid file-handle, then stop and debug that file-open code.

Comment: If i remove errors="ignore" the function dont open none doc file

Comment: Does it give errors? Post the error message here